# relative route from module child

Tags: angular-components, angular5

I'm improving my angular 5 project.

My first step is separate template, scss and typescript.

It's usually works without any problem, but some particular folders doesn't find the files and I cant understand what's happening.

This doesn't work, html and scss files are not found

```
@Component({
   selector: 'myComponetLevel3',
   template: './myComponentLevel3.component.html',
   styles: ['./myComponentLevel3.component.scss']
})
```

This works:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'myComponetLevel3',
   template: `<div class="myClass"></div>`,
   styles: [`
      .myClass {
           color: #aaaaaa;
      }
   `]
 })
```

The folder structure

```
--project_folder
  --src
    --app
      --myComponent
        --myComponentLevel2
          --myComponentLevel3
            --myComponentLevel3.component.ts
            --myComponentLevel3.component.scss
            --myComponentLevel3.component.html
```

How can I access to html and scss files?

Comment: Rather than editing your question to include the answer, move your answer into an actual dedicated answer then mark it as such.

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake.

I didn't change template <--> templateUrl and styles <--> stylesUrls. It should be:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'myComponetLevel3',
   templateUrl: './myComponentLevel3.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./myComponentLevel3.component.scss']
})
```